# Sockets in windows

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I wrote an example of programming sockets in Python.

```
# Prueba Sockets -Cliente-
import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("localhost", 9999))

while True:
      message = input("Enter the message: ")
      s.send(message)
      if message == "quit":
         break

print("Good bye")

s.close()

a = input("Enter key to End:")
```

While the server script is running I'd run the client script but it throws an error.

This is the output:

```
Enter the message: Try this.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/sajime/PycharmProjects/Learning/SocketClient.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.send(message)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Python 3.3 in Windows 7.

I'd tried with an integer instead the string, but it throws error too.

When the client stops by error the server goes to an endless loop printing empty messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3.x, [`socket.send`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send) accepts `bytes` object instead of `str` object. Encode the string.

Replace the following line:

```
s.send(message)
```

with:

```
s.send(message.encode())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
s.send(bytes(message, "UTF-8"))
```

Just like @falsetru said, the python 3.x api changed. You now need to send bytes instead of a string.

Comment: Well, you always needed to send bytes. Python 2 just made it easier to be confused about when you had bytes and when you had unicode strings, and things mostly worked coincidentally.

Comment: You're wrong, python2 socket.send api requires a string
`socket.send(string[, flags])` from http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

python3 requires bytes:
`socket.send(bytes[, flags])` http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send

I know you mean that in the end, the `string` becomes `bytes` but we wouldn't be talking about the python2/3 socket api.

Comment: Python 2 `str` objects are bytestrings.

Comment: Ok, but... the server receives bytes.  How convert the bytes received in a string before printing?

Comment: @Trimax: you `.decode()` them with the same codec you used to encode.

Comment: I replaced the client code with `s.send(bytes(message, 'UTF-8'))` and the server code with `received.decode('utf-8')` but the server doesn't  print any.

Comment: @Trimax `received.decode('utf8')` without the `-` between `utf` and `8`